# Is there a way to group by the date portion of a datetime field in SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

Is there a way (without creating a formula datevalue(datetime) field) to aggregate a SOQL query on the date portion of a datetime field? For example, I'd like to do something like:

`select datevalue(datetimeField), count(Id) from object__c group by datevalue(datetimeField)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While you can't group on a datetime field directly, there are a number of date/time functions for aggregates, so that you can group by part of the dateTime value. For example here's a query that'll show the number of account records created on each date.

```
select day_only(createdDate) createdonDate, 
    count(createdDate) numCreated 
    from account 
    group by day_only(createdDate) 
    order by day_only(createdDate) desc
```

The docs have details of all the [date functions for aggregates](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm).

day_only() returns the date part of a dateTime field.

Comment: That's good to know! Was also wondering if maybe using a formula field would work, though I've not tried it.

Comment: I completely missed day_only() when I read the docs. Thanks for pointing that out - it's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

According to the DescribeSObjectResult, datetime fields are not "groupable".